# Stop fglrx from loading on boot/unload fglrx module without uninstalling it

Tags: fedora, drivers, fglrx, proprietary-drivers

I have a Fedora 19 install on a laptop, which has Intel integrated graphics & discrete AMD graphics. I have been using the `radeon` driver, which works for most stuff - though I have recently tried the `fglrx` driver, and found it to be quite a bit faster and have better power management, though some OpenGL based programs won't run correctly.

So how can I disable the `fglrx` driver from loading upon boot, *so it fall backs onto the `radeon` driver*?

I have tried doing this by editing the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-fglrx.conf` file

```
# Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
# radeon conflicts with AMD Linux Graphics Driver
blacklist radeon
```

by commenting the `blacklist radeon` line, and adding `blacklist fglrx_pci

- List item

` below it. This just resulted in the GUI login screen not loading, so I had to switch to a TTY and edit back to what it was.

`lspci -k` with `fglrx` installed *(the only difference with it* not installed is `Subsystem: Lenovo Radeon HD 6370M/7370M` is not shown, and `radeon` is used as the AMD driver* - when just blacklisted *I think the only change is `radeon` is used)*:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397a
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: mei
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Robson CE [Radeon HD 6370M/7370M]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Radeon HD 6370M/7370M
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3979
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 051b
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9zjmyslrhmh9zv6/fglrx64_p_i_c-14.301.1001-1.x86_64.rpm?dl=0) is the RPM made by the installer *(the installer offers install directly or build packages for openSUSE or RedHat, I used the latest RedHat 64a option)*, and [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8kp8sm6s0znqi6e/fglrx64_p_i_c-14.301.1001-1.x86_64.rpm.scripts.txt) are the RPM install/uninstall scripts extracted from it.

---

I know about have tried using `modprobe` to remove the module when the system has booted - this does not work, resulting in `modprobe: FATAL: Module fglrx is in use`.

Blacklisting the driver *(and removing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` - one needs to be created after installing `fglrx` (it looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ntamqx82iu5bgsz/fglrx-xorg.conf.txt)), and fedora [does not need one anyway](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_xorg.conf) )* works in that the radeon driver is used instead - the problem here is that then quite a few applications don't work, and Gnome Shell & GDM show this:
[image: Oh no something has gone wrong GDM & GNOME error screen]

However, uninstalling the driver and rebooting always works.

---

For instance, applying this blacklist in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-fglrx.conf`:

```
# Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
# radeon conflicts with AMD Linux Graphics Driver
#blacklist radeon
blacklist fglrx
blacklist amd_iommu_v2
blacklist fglrx_pci
```

and removing `xorg.conf` results in the above GDM error. I can then (and have) switched to a TTY, and used `systemctl` to switch from GDM to LightDM and log into Xfce (which seems to work normally). Apps such as `cairo-dock` fail with segmentation faults. `glxinfo` gives:

```
name of display: :0.0
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

`systemctl` show this as GDM's status (before I switched to LightDM + Xfce), even though it crashed:

```
 gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2014-11-10 17:15:27 GMT; 1min 34s ago
 Main PID: 471 (gdm)
   CGroup: name=systemd:/system/gdm.service
           ├─ 471 /usr/sbin/gdm
           ├─ 597 /usr/libexec/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displays/_0
           ├─ 921 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -background none -verbose -auth /run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-l88Ufh/database -seat seat0 -nolisten tcp vt1
           └─1102 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-launch-environment]
```

and `lspci -k` is as follows:

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397a
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: mei
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Robson CE [Radeon HD 6370M/7370M]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Radeon HD 6370M/7370M
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3979
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 051b
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Here also are the logs from [`/var/log/gdm/:0.log`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mbvr12xs7k5yaed/fglrx-fail-gdm-%3A0-log.txt), [`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1027bk1x16b6i3t/fglrx-fail-Xorg-%3A0-log.txt) & [`/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ow793bxngbiya9k/fglrx-fail-Xorg-%3A0-log-old.txt) - I have checked the timestamps of each log, and I think the GDM & the old Xorg logs are the correct logs - the later Xorg log is the one from the current Xfce session, and should also be relevant.

I think the issue is either there is still some configuration somewhere telling it to use the fglrx driver, or there is a patched version of libGL (or something similar) which fglrx installed which needs fglrx (in which case this may be unsolvable.......).

Comment: use the modprobe command:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually just wrote a script that could be used to install and uninstall the driver, as well as set up the `xorg.conf` as my system required it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! $(whoami) = "root" ]]; then
    echo -e "\033[1;31mPlease run this as root\033[0m"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$1" = "enable" ]; then
    echo -e "\033[22;34mInstalling fglrx... ('/usr/share/fglrx64_p_i_c.x86_64')\033[1m\033[0m"
    sleep 3
    sudo rpm -ivh /usr/share/fglrx-amd-RPM/fglrx64_p_i_c-14.301.1001-1.x86_64.rpm
    if [ -f "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" ]; then
        echo "Backing up 'etc/X11/xorg.conf'"
        mv "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak.$(date)"
    fi
    echo "Preparing /etc/X11/xorg.conf"
    echo -e 'Section "ServerLayout"\n   Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"\n Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0\nEndSection\n\nSection "Module"\nEndSection\n\nSection "Monitor"\n   Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"\n Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"\n Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"\n   Option      "DPMS" "true"\nEndSection\n\nSection "Device"\n Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"\n   Driver      "fglrx"\n   BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"\nEndSection\n\nSection "Screen"\n   Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"\n    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"\n    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"\n   DefaultDepth     24\n   SubSection "Display"\n      Viewport   0 0\n        Depth     24\n  EndSubSection\nEndSection\n' > "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"

elif [ "$1" = "disable" ]; then
    echo "\033[22;34mUninstalling fglrx... ('fglrx64_p_i_c.x86_64')\033[1m\033[0m"
    sleep 3
    sudo rpm -ev fglrx64_p_i_c.x86_64
else
    lsmod | grep fglrx
    echo -e "\033[22;34mThe options for the script are 'enable' 'disable'\033[1m\033[0m"

fi
exit
```

I could of perhaps had a go at taking apart the [rpm scripts](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8kp8sm6s0znqi6e/fglrx64_p_i_c-14.301.1001-1.x86_64.rpm.scripts.txt) to see what it did during install/uninstall, but the above solution I think is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [modprobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modprobe) command. Assuming the drivers are called radeon and fglrx you can:

```
modprobe -r radeon 
modprobe -r fglrx
```

In order to check if those are really the right modules do a [lsmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsmod)

Assuming those procedures do what you need you can edit your [modules](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-kernel-modules-persistant.html)

Comment: I know about `modprobe` & `lsmod` - the problem is I want it to use `radeon`, and not use `fglrx_pci`/`fglrx`, and work.... also it usually just results in `modprobe: FATAL: Module NAME is in use.` `amd_iommu_v2` also appears to be part of `fglrx`.

Comment: Give me the exact command you used. And the exact message. Copy from terminal. The message suggests you did:
mod probe fglrx_pci/fglrx while I tolkd you to do 
modprobe -r fglrx_pci/fglrx which is a total different deal. Please use proper commands and show the proper output.

Comment: I did `modprobe -vr` - the `r` to remove the module, and the `v` to show what it did. Trying to use `modprobe` to load a already existing module does not show anything in terminal anyway :). The issue is that when fglrx is removed, `radoen` is loaded, but remaining configuration or some other issue (e.g. `xorg.conf` is one) means that the graphics don't work properly. I will add this in more detail to the question when I have time.